# How to make two columns unique As a combination?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table friends, defined as

UserId int PrimaryKey

OtherUserId int PrimaryKey

Currently, i have the following data

UserId   OtherUserId

1        2

I do not want duplicate enteries like

UserId   OtherUserId

2        1

how can i implement this using SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a computed column and then a unique index:

```
alter table friends UserId_least as (case when UserId < OtherUserId then UserId else OtherUserId end);

alter table friends UserId_greatest as (case when UserId < OtherUserId then OtherUserId else UserId end);

create unique index unq_friends_least_greatest
    on friends(UserId_least, UserId_greatest);
```

Comment: Although your approach is valid, but i would like to avoid the repeated data in the least and greatest userid columns... i was thinking more like a trigger if there are no other more intuitive means of doing it ... thanks for the idea ...

Comment: @Walid . . . What repeated data?  These are computed columns so they occupy no space (although the index *does* occupy space).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little broad. Please be advised that you can only have one primary key per table since it serves as the identification. As for the data, you could try to use auto increment and not null to avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: then first declare the columns that you want as a primary key as auto increment and not null, then set both table as a primary key on the next line through PRIMARY KEY(column name1, column name2)